# Spring Boot: Renaming the Main class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring and Spring Boot, but I'm using it as a template.

The Main.java file contains in part the following:

```
package com.example;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

}
```

Unfortunately I need to import another class that is called Main, and use it in this class. The other class is in a Jar and I don't really want to recompile it, so I was thinking the best way would be to rename this Main.

However when I do that (renaming it to JavaGettingStarted), the Maven plugin for Spring Boot will fail:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage
(default) on project java-getting-started: Execution default of goal
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage
failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following
candidates [com.example.JavaGettingStarted, com.example.Main] -> [Help
1]
```

Is Main some sort of default? Can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the name of the class, but rather that the Spring Boot Maven plugin detected two classes with a main method. Either delete one of those main methods, or explicitly configure the maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>Your class name here</mainClass>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I can recommend to have only a single main method in one class and not several of them. That makes working with Spring Boot simpler (conventions)..